# Cannot open output file name.exe permission denied in Eclipse C/C++

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm creating a C program in Eclipse and I get this error when I go to run my program. This is my first time using Eclipse for a C program I've only used Eclipse for java and never had any problems then so I'm not sure what is causing it. Now I'm using the Eclipse environment specifically for C/C++. So the program builds and debugs just fine but when I go to run it, it says "info: nothing to build" and also shows the permission denied error under "problems." I know this question has been asked and I've tried different solutions they suggested like changing certain windows settings, but nothing is working. Any ideas?

Comment: Permissions to run (or even open) a file are part of the operating system, not an IDE or a programming language.  What happens when you try to run your program at the command line?

Comment: I made a few changes and the permission denied error disappeared, but when I go to run the program I'm still getting "nothing to build." When I run the program in another IDE it works just fine so I feel like it may be a setting in Eclipse or something

Comment: the statement : nothing to build means that there has been no change to the source code since the last successful build, so there is no reason to build it again.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem with me while editing my code

### **The simplest solution **

- press the **red button**(Terminate) before editing your code then run your code

---

it is tested and works

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Windows: deactivate your antivirus.

Answer (score -1):

The same happened to me and I was sure there was no name.exe running.
In my case, make a clean build helped solve the problem.

**Project -> Clean** and then **Project -> Build All** should work

Answer (score -1):

Run as a administrator, because you do not have the admin access to the that file.

Answer (score -1):

Clean then build project again. It happens when you create additional files and removes before exit. edits files

Comment: This should have been a comment. It doesn't fully solve the question/provides proper explanation. I suggest you to read the answering guidelines on Stackoverflow.